# CheckState Indeterminate looping infinite times in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, checkboxlist

I'm trying to grayed out all items in the checkbox list except checked one when I check any checkbox in the list. Here is my trail, and it is going to infinite loop.

what is the issue? any idea?

```
private void CheckEveryOther_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var state = checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i);

        if (state != CheckState.Checked && state != CheckState.Indeterminate)
        {
             checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Indeterminate);
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: event -> loop -> inside loop `set` -> event ... ?

Comment: ItemCheck check event. I think this is causing issue. Is there any other option to achieve this?

Comment: have you actually debugged it to see what it's doing?

Comment: Are you trying to make a group of CheckBoxes like a group of Radio buttons?  If so, just use the Radio Buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void CheckEveryOther_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    {Control}.{ControlsEvent} -= new  EventHandler(CheckEveryOther_Click);

    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var state = checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i);

        if (state != CheckState.Checked && state != CheckState.Indeterminate)
        {
             checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Indeterminate);
        }
    } 

    {Control}.{ControlsEvent} += new  EventHandler(CheckEveryOther_Click);     
}
```

Replace {Control} with the control you are working with, and {ControlsEvent} with the control event that is being fired.

Comment: Thank you, it is not going to infinite loop now. But still I can able to select or unselect the Indeterminate checkboxes. Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: I got it,  if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Indeterminate)
            {
                e.NewValue = CheckState.Indeterminate;
            } thank you